# Django Tastypie, use other resource in obj_create method

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm playing around with tastypie, and is pretty much a newbie ;)

I have a FieldResource and want to call a EventLogResource every time there is field is created or updated ..

I think I have to use the obj_create method to call to EventLogResource this is my bad attempt..:

```
class FieldResource(ModelResource):
    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle = super(FieldResource, self).obj_create(bundle,**kwargs)
        # what to do here??
        EventLogResource.create_obj(user=bundle.request.user, comment="test").save()
        ...
```

Anyone know how to do this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Why resource? Create and save model.

```
EventLog(user=bundle.request.user, comment="test").save()
```

Comment: The problem is that this does not trigger the hydrate / dehydrate cycle on the resource, and some of my logic is located there for consistency.

Comment: What kind of logic? Maybe You can move it to other place?